# Run subprocess with several commands and detach to background keeping order

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm using the `subprocess` module to execute two commands:

```
import shlex    
from subprocess import check_call()

def comm_1(error_file):
    comm = shlex("mkdir /tmp/kde")
    try:
        check_call(comm)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        error_file.write("Error comm_1")

def comm_2(error_file):
    comm = shlex("ls -la /tmp/kde")
    try:
        check_call(comm)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        error_file.write("Error comm_2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("error_file", "r+") as log_error_file:
         comm_1(log_error_file)
         comm_2(log_error_file)
         log_error_file.write("Success")
```

I'm aware of a few pitfalls in this design, like the `error_file` being shared with the functions. This is easily refactored, though. What I'm trying to do is to detach the entire process to background. I would accomplish this with

```
 check_call(comm, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

But this would pose a race problem, because I want to make sure that `comm_1` is finished before `comm_2` starts. What is the best approach to do this with `subprocess`? I can't use `python-daemon` or other packages outside the standard Python 2.6 library.

EDIT: I could try to use something like

```
nohup python myscript.py &
```

But the ideia is to have only one way to start the job from the python script.

Comment: Seems like you could change things so that `if __name__ == "__main__"` myscript.py spawned something that does what you're currently doing e at the end. With the right conditionals, that could probably be _itself_.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow. Should I remove the functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to make sure the process inside of `comm_1` dies before starting the subprocess call within `comm_2` by using [`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait). But to do so, you're going to have to use [`Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead of `check_call()`.

```
from subprocess import Popen

def comm_1(error_file):
    comm = shlex("mkdir /tmp/kde")
    try:
        proc_1 = Popen(comm)
        proc_1.wait(timeout=20)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError, TimeoutExpired:
        error_file.write("Error comm_1")
```

`proc_1.wait()` is going to wait for 20 seconds (you can change the time) for the process to finish before continuing. If it takes longer than 20 secs, it's going to throw a `TimeoutExpired` exception, which you can catch in your `except` block.

Comment: Thanks. With `Popen` `wait` method, would the father process be detached? The sequence should be something like `start python process` -> `detach both functions` -> `comm_1 executes` -> `comm_2 executes`, without the father process still be present.

Comment: @Ivan Just to clarify, do you mean if the python script would completely execute and finish while `comm_1` and `comm_2` continue executing in the background until they also finish?

Comment: Exactly. The python script is a "launcher" and should exit while `comm_1` and `comm_2` runs in background.

Comment: @Ivan Unfortunately no.. It completely halts the python process and waits for the `comm_1` subprocess to finish before continuing to execute the rest of the python script.

Comment: @Ivan I'm not completely sure this works, but if you use `Popen(comm, close_fds=True)`, I believe the python process continues without waiting for `proc_1` to finish, but then you might enter a race condition with `comm_2`. You can give it a try if you like.